# Searching for the name of a well-known theorem in field theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, finite-fields

The following theorem is well-known:

> If $K$ is a finite field, then $(K^{\times}, \cdot)$ is a cyclic group.

I wonder if there is a name whose this theorem is attributed to.

Comment: I don't know any, but there's a more general formulation, which does not depend upon $K$ being  finite: *Any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group* $K^\times$ *of a field is cyclic.*

Comment: Maybe useful: *A history of Galois fields* (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00786662/document).